# Remote control iPad

Tags: remote-desktop, ipad, ios

I've been looking around and only found a couple of enterprise (price) level solutions for remote controlling an iPad/iPhone. Does anyone know of any cheap or free software out there that will allow me to control an IOS device from my PC/Mac?

Answer (score 1):

I seem to remember that if the device is Jailbroken there are some free VNC servers for iPhone.
Otherwise just buy one I suppose at least I wasn't able to find one free of charge.

Comment: Cydia does have VNC clients and most likely would have VNC servers as well... But, from my experience, VNC is often the worst and oldest option to remote controlling anything - there's always something newer and better.

Answer (score 1):

If you jailbreak your device, you can install Veency (search Cydia for it) and then use any VNC client to remote-control your iPad.

That said, the experience isn't all that great since the iPad isn't particularly fast at delivering the screen's contents, and things are a bit strange controlling your iPad (which is inherently touch-based) with your mouse.

That said, it's free. Changes are good, though, that your other, more expensive options are probably better. Put it this way: I installed it, played with it, and then have barely used it since. The experience isn't good enough for me. (Plus, I'd rather save the iPad's precious resources for actual apps.)